# Import multiple files from directory with loop

Tags: python, json, for-loop, import

I'm trying to import multiple .json files from a directory and am getting stuck. The directory has more than just .json files in it. I realize I need to import using a loop, but am pretty new to all of this. Any help? Here's my code thus far:

```
import os
path = "/Users/jkelson/Desktop/JsonFiles/Project3"
directory = os.listdir(path)

for x in directory:
    if x.endswith('.json'):
        with open(x) as input_file:
            jsondata = json.load(input_file)
```

So you are saying change it to this??

```
import os
path = "/Users/jkelson/Desktop/JsonFiles/Project3"
directory = os.path.join(path, x)

for x in directory:
    if x.endswith('.json'):
        with open(x) as input_file:
            jsondata = json.load(input_file)
```

Pretty apparent that I'm new to this, I apologize. This is also my first post so forgive me if I make mistakes in how the community comments.

In the directory there are multiple .json files, with varying names that I'm trying to open and store in a dataframe for analysis.

```
import os
path = "/Users/jkelson/Desktop/JsonFiles/Project3"
directory = os.listdir(path)

for x in directory:
    if x.endswith('.json'):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, x)
        with open(full_path) as input_file:
            jsondata = json.load(input_file)
```

Comment: What aspect of this are you "stuck" on?  What is wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: I get this error: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-ab199c8079a9> in <module>()
      6     if x.endswith('.json'):
      7         with open(x) as input_file:
----> 8             jsondat = json.load(input_file)

Comment: The problem is that you are using the name of the file without including the path. Use `os.path.join(path, x)`

Comment: Post updates to the question *in the question*, please.

Comment: No, inside the loop. Your error is happening when you run `open(x)` because `x` is just the file name, not the full path to the file.

Comment: You really should test code before you post it.

Comment: @ScottHunter - I have been testing, and it's not working for me and I keep getting errors. I've scoured the web to try and understand and learn. This is why I turned to this community. I am new to coding, hoping to get some help from all the experience and knowledge here.

Comment: I was referring to your "are you saying try this?" edit, which clearly did not work, but you gave no indication that you had actually tried it, much less tried to fix it.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I tried it yes, but still didn't work. I will be more clear next time. The last piece of code I also tried, but it also gives me errors (too long to paste here, but it says valueerror.

Answer (score 0):

As zondo points out, your error is happening because you are trying to open a file that doesn't exist in the directory you are running from. You need to provide the full path to the file in your `open()` statement. Consider revising to something like:

```
full_path = os.path.join(path, x)
with open(full_path) as input_file:
     # Rest of your code here
```